# why rmarkdown stops generating .tex file when finds an accent?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, xelatex

I have a problem but I don't know exactly its origin. When I knit a rmarkdown document with accents in the text such as *á, é, í, ó, ú*, the .tex file stops being generated at that point, and R gives the following error:

> Emergency stop.
> rmarkdown_file.tex
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile rmarkdown_file.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See rmarkdown_file.log for more info.

I've tried installing TinyTeX, MacTex, older and newer versions of R and RStudio, and added the following front matter:

```
output:
pdf_document: 
latex_engine: xelatex
toc: true
extra_dependencies: ["float"]
html_document:
df_print: paged
word_document: default
always_allow_html: true
editor_options: 
markdown: 
wrap: sentence
encoding: UTF-8
header-includes:
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I don't know if the problem if with the knit, the pandoc or the LaTeX distribution. In other computer it does work, but in my M1 Mac it always crashes.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a language in the YAML? (e.g., `lang: fr` or `lang:es`). [Here's a link to R's YAML guide.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ymlthis/vignettes/yaml-fieldguide.html)

Comment: Other than the missing indentation of the header, I do get a pdf with accents https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yURS.png Can you show your intermediate .tex file and the .log file so we can see which tex distribution etc. you use?

Answer (score 0):

Update: a few weeks after I updated the RStudio version and it run properly. I believe that some sort of encoding trouble may have occurred while reading R files.